# What's a good app for managing media files?

Tags: media-player, files

I prefer to manually organize my media (music, podcasts, video) on my SD card using a file manager (as opposed to letting the media player organize it all by tags, because it mixes music with podcasts and doesn't organize untagged files).

I've been using the "File Manager" app which works fine, but the problem is when I select and play a file with it, it will play in the player of my choice but when I 'minimize' the player the audio stops.   It seems that when I manually select a file to play it's not opening the file and letting it run in the background while I multitask.

Any tips or app recommendations appreciated !

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but it might help: I use BeyondPod to download,manage and play podcasts and there's an option to hide podcasts from Android's Media Server (which scans folders looking for media files) so my podcasts never show up in my Music Player.  So when I want to listen to music I open the "Music" app and when I want to play a podcast I open BeyondPod.

Comment: Cool, good tip Matt - thanks I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this: [Music Folder Player](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853159)

Comment: Wow, good timing - I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

How do you"minimize" ? Pressing the BACK key is almost akin to quitting. However, pressing the HOME key usually allows you to multi-task and allows the currently running app to carry on in the background.

Try pressing the HOME key to see if the audio continues so you can then switch to whichever app you like.

You can try the Meridian Player - it allows navigation via specified folders and the freeware version should work fine for you. Multi-tasking / background playback is definitely part of the feature-set.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the HOME key.  Seems that when you open a file with FIle Manager, it will open it in an external app but any navigation away from it and it will quit back to FIle manager.  As if File Manager is the parent.  And hence, you can't get audio files to play in the background when multitasking.